# Is there a way to continue typing in the same Terminal tab after running a .command file?

Tags: terminal, macos

For example, let's say I want to set up my Python Virtual Environment. I would run `python3 -m virtualenv env` wait for it to run, then run `source /Users/MyAccountName/env/bin/activate` and then I would change my directory to wherever I want to be running Python files. 
It would be much easier to simply set that up in a `.command` file, so I can double click it and have it set up the Virtual Environment. However, when I run a `.command` file, once it is finished running, it simply prints:

```
logout
[Process Completed]
```

And I can't type anything anymore.
So, is there anyway for me to continue typing in the same Terminal tab after running a `.command` file?

Comment: Could you do this in a shell script instead?

Comment: At the time of writing this, `.sh`, `.bash`, `.ksh`, `.zsh`, `.csh`, `.tcsh`, and `.bcsh` all have the same effect. I can't continue typing after the command has been run.

Comment: I've run apps before and followed the command with & to tun it in the background. This enables the user to continue using the terminal window while the app is running.